# AdMob and GDPR which ad technology providers to select?

Tags: admob

Today in my AdMob UI I was prompted to configure the EU consent stuff

There is 2 choice, "Commonly used set of ad technology providers" and "Custom set of ad technology providers".

If I chose the first choice then I cannot use Google's ConsentForm. However I have no idea what ad technology providers I need to choose in order to not affect my ad revenue

Does selecting "Google" is enough ?

Comment: Less providers means less ads to show.

Comment: So i'm better of letting the default ones and simple not target EU users (npa:1). I don't like showing annoying popup to aks the user if they want ads..

Comment: With Google consent api you can check if the user is located in europe and therefore show the dialog consent. But Google consent api only supports up to 12 providers. So you have to make a choice: Choose "Custom set of ad technology providers" and use Google Consent form, or choose "Commonly used set of ad technology providers" and make your own consent form.

Comment: @Simon Do you know, which 12 ads providers I should choose, and will selecting "Custom set of ad technology providers" affect revenue for Non EU?

Comment: Interestingly, I wonder if anyone has been able to confirm that sending npa, 1 along with the Ad Request actually *does* return a non-personalized ad?

Comment: @ Cheok Yan Cheng I wish I know